# SVN project not showing in repository directory

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

> TortoiseSVN 1.7.15,
>
> Subversion 1.7.18,

I imported my project from a windows workstation using tortoise svn to an existing repository on a CentOS server.

My directory structure is as follows:
SpringProject/trunk/[project files and dirs  src/ resources/ etc.]
SpringProject/branch and SpringProject/tags

I highlighted SpringProject directory in the explorer interface, right clicked and selected SVN Import, entered a log message and clicked OK. The project was imported with no errors

The project directory and subdirectories in my windows interface show the green check marks signifying everything is good.

The Problem:
However, on the CentOS server in the repos directory /usr/local/svn/repos, the SpringProject entry does not appear alongside of my other projects.

If I use Tortoise repo browser, it shows the project and the url I expect.  The SpringProject is shown in the interface alongside of my other projects.

I changed out of the /usr/local/svn/repos directory and back in to see if the shell needed to reread the directory.  The entry is still not there.  svn list --verbose svn/192.168.0.76/usr/local/svn/repos shows the SpringProject along with my other projects.

Restart/reload of the svnserve service does not change anything.  If I try a commit on the directory, the interface says nothing to commit, no files have changed.  So Tortoise sees everything as OK.

I suppose I might delete the project and reimport from the command line, but I would like to know the reason this occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently these directories were the results of errors in attempts to create these projects.  They were empty except for trunk/tag/branches directories.  A simple rm -Rf cleaned it up with no side issues.